# ill-conditioning

Tags: optimization, conditioning

I am struggling with the following exercise from the book of [Nocedal, Numerical optimization](http://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-40065-5), chapter 2, exercise 2.12:

Suppose that a function $f$ of two variables is poorly scaled at the solution $x^*$. Write two Taylor expansions of $f$ around $x^*$ - one along each coordinate direction - and use them to show that the Hessian $\nabla^2 f (x^*)$ is ill-conditioned.

Comment: Well, have you written down the Taylor expansions? Do you know the definition of ill-conditioned (and "poorly scaled")?

Comment: I have written Taylor expansions, however book does not provide exact definitions of ill-conditioned and poorly scaled. I am mostly struggling with cross-terms of hessian.

Comment: Then you should update your question with the details on exactly what you are struggling with; in its current form, it's unclear what a helpful answer would be. (The more detail you put in a question, the more inclined people are to spend the time trying to answer it.)

Comment: (For the purposes of this question, a matrix is ill-conditioned if small changes in the right-hand side would lead to very large changes in the solution of the corresponding linear equation system.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help to start with a concrete example of a function, like $f(x,y)=10^9 x^2+y^2$ (the example they use on p.26). I'm trying to guess what went wrong with your analysis, because you haven't given much information.

> I am mostly struggling with cross-terms of hessian.

Consider
$$f_1(x,y) = 10^9 x^2+y^2$$
and its rotation by $\theta=\frac\pi4$
$$f_2(x,y) = 10^9 (x\cos\theta + y\sin\theta)^2 + (-x\sin\theta + y\cos\theta)^2.$$
These are equivalent, and both are poorly scaled, but in different directions. If you try to analyze the Hessian in a way that just assumes that the function is poorly scaled *specifically in the coordinate directions* (only the diagonal terms are important, and so you don't care about cross terms), it's not going to work for the second function. I think you just need a different way of proving ill-conditionedness of the Hessian.